# is ondestroy() called by the main gui thread?

Tags: android

is ondestroy() in an activity called by the main gui thread? I always assumed it would be, but i can't find any documentation saying so, and now I have a bug which might indicate it's not running in the main thread.

Or maybe my loop code is broken.

Comment: From the Android docs on Processes and Threads (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html): "The system does not create a separate thread for each instance of a component. All components that run in the same process are instantiated in the UI thread, and system calls to each component are dispatched from that thread. Consequently, methods that respond to system callbacks (such as onKeyDown() to report user actions **or a lifecycle callback method**) always run in the UI thread of the process."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, onDestroy is called on Main UI thread..Post you code to check the error.

Comment: And newer mind my code. I just realized my code did just what it should. Just not what I needed.